# Remove one of the two legends produced in this Seaborn figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn, figure

I have just started using seaborn to produce my figures. However I can't seem to remove one of the legends produced here.

I am trying to plot two  accuracies against each other and draw a line along the diagonal to make it easier to see which has performed better (if anyone has a better way of plotting this data in seaborn - let me know!). The legend I'd like to keep is the one on the left, that shows the different colours for 'N_bands' and different shapes for 'Subject No'

```
ax1 = sns.relplot(y='y',x='x',data=df,hue='N bands',legend='full',style='Subject No.',markers=['.','^','<','>','8','s','p','*','P','X','D','H','d']).set(ylim=(80,100),xlim=(80,100))
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x=range(80,110),y=range(80,110),legend='full')
```

[image]

I have tried setting the kwarg legend to 'full','brief' and False for both ax1 and ax2 (together and separately) and it only seems to remove the one on the left, or both.

I have also tried to remove the axes using matplotlib

```
ax1.ax.legend_.remove()
ax2.legend_.remove()
```

But this results in the same behaviour (left legend dissapearing).

UPDATE: Here is a minimal example you can run yourself:

```
test_data = np.array([[1.,2.,100.,9.],[2.,1.,100.,8.],[3.,4.,200.,7.]])
test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y','p','q'], data=test_data)

sns.set_context("paper")
ax1=sns.relplot(y='y',x='x',data=test_df,hue='p',style='q',markers=['.','^','<','>','8'],legend='full').set(ylim=(0,4),xlim=(0,4))
ax2=sns.lineplot(x=range(0,5),y=range(0,5),legend='full')
```

[image]

Although this doesn't reproduce the error perfectly as the right legend is coloured (I have no idea how to reproduce this error then - does the way my dataframe was created make a difference?). But the essence of the problem remains - how do I remove the legend on the right but keep the one on the left?

Comment: Any chance you can provide a runnable code which we can use? Currently we can't even run your code

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: not 100% sure, but I think if you change `legend='full'` to `legend=False` for either the `relplot` or the `lineplot`, that should remove a legend.

Comment: I'm afraid I've tried that, and it only seems to remove both legends or the one i want to keep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're plotting a lineplot in the (only) axes of a `FacetGrid` produced via `relplot`. That's quite unconventional, so strange things might happen.

One option to remove the legend of the FacetGrid but keeping the one from the lineplot would be

```
g._legend.remove()
```

Full code (where I also corrected for the confusing naming if grids and axes)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

test_data = np.array([[1.,2.,100.,9.],[2.,1.,100.,8.],[3.,4.,200.,7.]])
test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y','p','q'], data=test_data)

sns.set_context("paper")
g=sns.relplot(y='y',x='x',data=test_df,hue='p',style='q',markers=['.','^','<','>','8'], legend='full')

sns.lineplot(x=range(0,5),y=range(0,5),legend='full', ax=g.axes[0,0])

g._legend.remove()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this is kind of a hack, and it might break in future seaborn versions.

The other option is to not use a FacetGrid here, but just plot a scatter and a line plot in one axes,

```
ax1 = sns.scatterplot(y='y',x='x',data=test_df,hue='p',style='q',
                      markers=['.','^','<','>','8'], legend='full')

sns.lineplot(x=range(0,5),y=range(0,5), legend='full', ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the conventional way to plot the line on top of the scatter plot? Should I use something instead of relpot?

Comment: @bidby : How about a simple `plt.plot()`?

Comment: I'd be ok with that, but my supervisor specifcally told me to use seaborn - although I guess they'll never know if I just use plt.plot() for the line...

Comment: I updated the answer with what I would consider the "conventional" way of plotting this.

Comment: This gives me a `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_legend'` error

Comment: @emilaz try using 'legend_' instead of '_legend'