# Why is Seaborn plotting two legends, how do I remove one and fix the other?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, legend

When I run the code shown below I get a figure containing 2 legends. I can't figure out why two are being plotted and I havent been able to remove one of them. My aim is to keep the legend that is outside of the figure, remove the one thats inside the figure and also somehow stop the weird cropping that is cutting off the right side of the legend outside the figure. [image: figure showing the two legends with random data]

I had a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665087/remove-one-of-the-two-legends-produced-in-this-seaborn-figure) asking something similar, but that issue was solved by using seaborns scatterplot instead of the relplot. Sadly neither of the answers that worked in that question work here. If this problem is arising out of an "uncoventional" way of plotting the type of figure I'm trying to make, then please let me know. Doing it properly is better than hacking your way to the solution...

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd


    #setup
    sns.set(font_scale=2)
    sns.set_context('poster')

    #figure and axes
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
    axs = {i:fig.add_subplot(330+i) for i in range(1,10)}




    #create random data
    r = np.random.randint
    N=10
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['No.','x1','x2','x3','y1','y2','y3'])
    for i in range(N):
        df.loc[i] = i+1,r(50,high=100),r(50,high=100),r(50,high=100),r(50,high=100),r(50,high=100),r(50,high=100)

    #create axes labels
    x_labels = ['x1','x2','x3']
    y_labels = ['y1','y2','y3']
    xy_labels = [(x,y) for y in y_labels for x in x_labels ]


    #plot on axes
    for i,(x_label,y_label) in enumerate(xy_labels):
        if i ==0:#if statement so only one of the plots has legend='full'
            a = sns.scatterplot(
                data=df,
                x=x_label,
                y=y_label,
                legend='full', #create the legend
                ax=axs[i+1],
                hue='No.',
                palette=sns.color_palette("hls", N)
            )

            fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.7), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.) #Move the legend outside the plot
            a.legend_.remove() #attempt to remove the legend
        else:
            a = sns.scatterplot(
                data=df,
                x=x_label,
                y=y_label,
                legend=False,
                ax=axs[i+1],
                hue='No.',
                palette=sns.color_palette("hls", N)
            )

        #remove axes labels from specific plots
        if i not in [0,3,6]: axs[i+1].set_ylabel('')
        if i not in [6,7,8]: axs[i+1].set_xlabel('')


    #add line plots and set limits        
    for ax in axs.values():
        sns.lineplot(x=range(50,100),y=range(50,100), ax=ax, linestyle='-')
        ax.set_xlim([50,100])
        ax.set_ylim([50,100])


    fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Missing legend false.     #add line plots and set limits        
    for ax in axs.values():
        sns.lineplot(x=range(50,100),y=range(50,100), ax=ax, linestyle='-',legend=False)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `legend=False` in the last part of your code.

```
#setup
sns.set(font_scale=2)
sns.set_context('poster')

#figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
axs = {i:fig.add_subplot(330+i) for i in range(1,10)}

#create axes labels
x_labels = ['x1','x2','x3']
y_labels = ['y1','y2','y3']
xy_labels = [(x,y) for y in y_labels for x in x_labels ]

#plot on axes
for i,(x_label,y_label) in enumerate(xy_labels):
    if i ==0:#if statement so only one of the plots has legend='full'
        a = sns.scatterplot(
            data=df,
            x=x_label,
            y=y_label,
            legend='full', #create the legend
            ax=axs[i+1],
            hue='No.',
            palette=sns.color_palette("hls", N)
       )
        fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.7), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.) #Move the legend outside the plot
        a.legend_.remove() #attempt to remove the legend
    else:
        a = sns.scatterplot(
            data=df,
            x=x_label,
            y=y_label,
            legend=False,
            ax=axs[i+1],
            hue='No.',
            palette=sns.color_palette("hls", N)
        )

    #remove axes labels from specific plots
    if i not in [0,3,6]: axs[i+1].set_ylabel('')
    if i not in [6,7,8]: axs[i+1].set_xlabel('')

#add line plots and set limits        
for ax in axs.values():
    sns.lineplot(x=range(50,100),y=range(50,100), ax=ax, linestyle='-', legend=False)
    ax.set_xlim([50,100])
    ax.set_ylim([50,100])

fig.tight_layout()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ah. Oops. Thanks. Do you have any idea why the legend is being cropped?

Comment: You can adjust that with: fig.tight_layout(pad=0.5, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=0.5)